# Pc not turning on

Tags: desktop-computer, power-management

So i have a power cut every once in a while and few weeks earlier after a power cut and came back i turned on my pac but it just flashed its lights as a flickering and didn’t turn on. I changed the cmos battery also thinking it was the fault of a dead batrery. But it didn’t turn on as it should. The thing is it turns on after fiddling with the power button. It doesnt have any specific time limit for it to turn on. Its random but the pc turns on well after a while. What could be the problem?

Note : after turning on it works perfectly fine as if nothing happened.

Comment: It can be a power inbalance. You could try to unplug the power cord, so the system does not get any power anymore, now hold the powerbutton for 30 seconds to drain all residual power, plug the power back in and try again.

Comment: @LPChip i did that too. But the lights flickers once again and no power.

Comment: If power cuts are that frequent and cause problems, better buy an UPS for protection.

Comment: @harrymc yeah but i have to turn on the pc first

Comment: Your post is unclear : "after turning on it works perfectly fine as if nothing happened". What kind of fiddling with the power button?

Comment: Have you tried jump-starting the PSU with a paperclip? It could be the motherboard that's faulty. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1dcJ0QyAE

Comment: @harrymc i just keep clicking the power button. If it was the dead motherboard it would not have been flickering. The power supply seems fine as well.

Comment: @spikey_richie ill try it once. After few hours of fiddling. The pc is on. But i dont know for sure if i shut it down and turn it back again, the problem persists

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is just with the power button? You may test it by short-circuiting the button with a screw-driver (example [link](https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/2011-jumping-a-motherboard-without-power-switch-button) but there are many).